# Simple Android activity for displaying Facebook timeline?

Tags: android, facebook, timeline

I am writing an Android App for a charity, and would like to be able to display the charity's facebook feed within the App. I don't want it to go through the phone's web browser, nor the facebook app.

I read on the developers.facebook.com how to add facebook's android sdk to the app's build gradle. But what I can't find is code for a simple android activity that will display the facebook timeline. I don't have time to dive deep into facebook's sdk to fiigure it out. And the last thing I want to do is reinvent the wheel.

Can anyone point me towards some code for a simple activity to display a facebook timeline? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you got so far? Have you looked at this? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed (click Android under 'Reading')

Answer (score 0):

I'm not home so I can't test this right now but it should work.

In your layout file, put a webview like so:

```
<WebView
android:id="@+id/mWebView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Then in the onCreate method:

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mWebView);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://LinkToFacebookPage.com/");
```

And finally, in your manifest file put the following permission before < Application >

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to view the timeline through the phone's browser. I want to read the timeline directly into a fragment on my App's home screen.